# ROS Answers SE migration: imwrite error

Tags: c++, opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
cv::imwrite("/home/jros/image.jpg",cv_ptr->image);
```

I want to save an image using imwrite but I get this error when I launch the node:

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (could not find a writer for the specified extension) in imwrite_, file /home/guillaume/Developpement/libs/OpenCV-2.2.0/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp, line 276
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/guillaume/Developpement/libs/OpenCV-2.2.0/modules/highgui/src/loadsave.cpp:276: error: (-2) could not find a writer for the specified extension in function imwrite_

Aborted (core dumped)
```

there is no error in compilation.
It seems like an error in OpenCV version !?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187836/imwrite-error/) by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on ROS Answers with karma: 751 on 2014-07-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-07-28**:
It would be better if you ask this question in StackOverflow, as I see that you are using a standalone OpenCV version. And by the way try updating your OpenCV first and retry, because your version is REALLY old. You could also try the cvSaveImage (old C implementation of imwrite) , docs on this link http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imwrite

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2014-07-28**:
Instead of StackOverflow it would be even better to ask your question in http://answers.opencv.org

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-07-28**:
cvSaveImage is in C but I'm using C++ so it's imwrite.
ya as I said maybe it's an old opencv version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solutions that I found:

Either you change the OpenCV version to the latest one or use another library to save the image, example Visp:

```
#include <visp/vpImageConvert.h>
#include <visp/vpImageIo.h>

Mat image_mat;  
vpImageConvert::convert (image_mat, image_visp); //convert image_mat to image_visp
vpImageIo::write(image_visp,"*.jpg"); //save (you will find the image in /../../catkin_ws/*.jpg)
```

---

Originally posted by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) with karma: 751 on 2014-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sounds like it is unable to use *.jpg files. Try another format?

---

Originally posted by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) with karma: 644 on 2014-07-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2014-07-28**:
I tried all these extensions .pgm .jpg .png

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What kind of image is *cv_ptr->image*? According to [OpenCV 2.2 documentation](http://opencv.jp/opencv-2.2_org/cpp/highgui_reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html):

> Only 8-bit (or 16-bit in the case of PNG, JPEG 2000 and TIFF) single-channel or 3-channel (with ‘BGR’ channel order) images can be saved using this function.

Make sure that *cv_ptr->image* is an 8 bit single-channel or 3-channel image.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2014-07-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1